# Where am I supposed to sudo apt-get install to?

Tags: node.js, heroku, puppeteer, chromium, sudo

So I'm trying to use Puppeteer in a Node.js project that I'm deploying to Heroku. I have the Heroku build pack in place, I am sure my Puppeteer code is right (pulled it straight from the docs), but I'm getting this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/42obk.png

After a bit of research, I realized that I think I have to sudo apt-get install chromium-browser (I'm on Mac by the way, which I THINK [not sure] is Unix). My question is, where am I supposed to install it? Is this even the right command/thing to do based on the error above? Do I just install when I'm in my ~ directory, or do I cd into the project folder, or what? Thanks for any/all help in advance!

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched, copied, or consumed at all by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Specifically, what do you mean by "I have the Heroku build pack in place"?

Comment: (You shouldn't be using `apt-get` on macOS, but you also shouldn't be using it on Heroku due to its [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).)

Comment: "Unable to open X display" means the server doesn't have a graphical environment (which makes sense). You'll need to run in headless mode. Can't help much more than that based on what you've shared. Very often, the code people are most sure about is the code that needs to change...

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, thanks haha